# EF delete a reference in bridge table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 entities Group and User. 1 'Group' has a collection of users and 1 'User' has a collection of groups. I want to delete a record in the bridge table

```
Group: GroupID, name
User: UserID, name
GroupUser (bridge table): GroupID, UserID
```

currently I have

```
var query = from u in context.User
                        from g in u.Group
                        where u.UserID==1 && g.GroupID==10
```

But then how do I delete the record in the bridge table with the matching UserID and GroupID. query.Clear() returns error

Edit: in my EF, there is no object to represent the bridge table. so I cannot user context.UserGroup(...) should I create an object for the bridge table? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is bridge table?

Comment: many-to-many relationship table

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your bridge table is named `UserGroup(s)`

```
var group = context.UserGroup.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == 1 && x.GroupID == 10);
if (group != null)
{
    context.DeleteObject(group);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
else
    //Do something in response
```

Comment: Why `First` instead of `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault`) if the composite key is `UserId`+`GroupId`, any combination would be unique no? Just wondering..

Comment: I agree, and changed my answer.  `SingleOrDefault` would be more appropriate for a bridge table.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. in my EF, there is no object to represent the bridge table. so I cannot user context.UserGroup(...). Is there any other way?

Comment: Easiest way would be to add your bridge table to your EDM.  You could also create a Stored Procedure to do the delete and add that it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should select from your bridge table:

```
var results = from bt in context.BridgeTable 
               where bt.UserID = 1 and bt.GroupID = 1
foreach(var result in results)
{
     context.DeleteObject(result);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Note if `results` has 0 items, `context.SaveChanges()` gets called without any changes made; is there any impact to this?